# How to Record The View on Tensorflow Lite Android Project

Tags: android, tensorflow, screen-recording

I learned how to apply the code in this example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android

Currently, I successfully built the project and installed it on an Android device. But now comes my question, how to record the view when the tensorflow with the camera works? I want to record the situation when TensorFlow works with the recognized object and save it to the device's memory.

Any Idea for my Questions? Thank you.

Comment: Please add your code and your attempt so we can help you further.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav Note that an attempt is not required for how-to questions; that said, this question could use some more explanation, which might include code.